# How to create multiple onAction listeners for a single button?

Tags: button, javafx, onclicklistener

I'm creating a card game, and I believe I have all the Java classes down. But the user entry JavaFX part I'm struggling with. I created a `TextArea` to display messages to the user, and a `TextField` to be filled by the user. The user then presses the button, the `TextArea`'s text should change, the program should store the value, and then they should be able to repeat the process.
When I place the `onAction` listeners one after the other, the program runs all of the listeners at the same time. Is there a way to stack the listeners so that they happen consecutively with each following button click? Or do I have to create new scenes for each button click? I feel maybe this should be intuitive, but after spending days googling and trying, I'm at a loss. TYIA.

The next listener should take in the $$ amount to add to player bank, then the text area should change and ask the user for a bet amount for the round, etc.

Here's a snippet of just my JavaFX:

```java
package blackjack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author toril
 */
public class BlackJack extends Application {

    //"topPane" will reveal the area to be maniplated by player
    public GridPane getTopPane(){
        GridPane topPane = new GridPane();
        
        //SCENE ONE
        
        //first section
        //create textarea for the game's prompts
        TextArea gameplayTA = new TextArea("Welcome to the table.\nWhat is your name?");
        gameplayTA.setEditable(false);
        gameplayTA.setPrefRowCount(3);
        gameplayTA.setPrefColumnCount(3);
        
        //create hbox to hold the edittext for user input
        HBox userEntryHB = new HBox();
        TextField userEntryTF = new TextField("");
        Button userEntryBtn = new Button("ENTER");
        //if user hasnt enetered anything, cannot trigger button event
        userEntryBtn.disableProperty().bind(userEntryTF.textProperty().isEmpty());
        //add user entry area to hbox
        userEntryHB.getChildren().addAll(userEntryTF, userEntryBtn);
        //add margin
        HBox.setMargin(userEntryTF, new Insets(10, 5, 10, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(userEntryBtn, new Insets(10, 5, 10, 0));
        
        //add textarea and HBox to VBox
        VBox gameplayVB = new VBox();
        gameplayVB.getChildren().addAll(gameplayTA, userEntryHB);
        //add margin
        VBox.setMargin(gameplayTA, new Insets(10, 5, 5, 10));
        VBox.setMargin(userEntryHB, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10));
        
        //add nodes to gridpane
        topPane.getChildren().add(gameplayVB);
        GridPane.setConstraints(gameplayVB, 0, 0);
        //end first section

        
        //second section - scores/bank/bet
        //textfields to store dynamic information
        TextField playerBankTF = new TextField("");
        playerBankTF.setEditable(false);
        TextField compBankTF = new TextField("");
        compBankTF.setEditable(false);
        TextField betAmountTF = new TextField("");
        betAmountTF.setEditable(false);
        TextField playerScoreTF = new TextField("");
        playerScoreTF.setEditable(false);
        TextField compScoreTF = new TextField("");
        compScoreTF.setEditable(false);
        
        //set widths
        playerBankTF.setPrefWidth(80);
        compBankTF.setPrefWidth(80);
        betAmountTF.setPrefWidth(80);
        playerScoreTF.setPrefWidth(40);
        compScoreTF.setPrefWidth(40);
        
        //labels for textfield
        Label playerBankLbl = new Label("Player Bank: ", playerBankTF);
        Label compBankLbl = new Label("Computer Bank: ", compBankTF);
        Label betAmountLbl = new Label("Bet Amount: ", betAmountTF);
        Label playerScoreLbl = new Label("Player Score: ", playerScoreTF);
        Label compScoreLbl = new Label("Computer Score: ", compScoreTF);
        //put labels on correct side
        playerBankLbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
        compBankLbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
        betAmountLbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
        playerScoreLbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
        compScoreLbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
        
        //hbox to hold current amount of $$ in both bank accounts
        HBox hbOne = new HBox();
        hbOne.getChildren().addAll(playerBankLbl, compBankLbl);
        HBox.setMargin(playerBankLbl, new Insets(20, 10, 10, 10));
        HBox.setMargin(compBankLbl, new Insets(20, 10, 10, 10));
        
        //hbox to hold only bet amount
        HBox hbTwo = new HBox();
        hbTwo.getChildren().add(betAmountLbl);
        HBox.setMargin(betAmountLbl, new Insets(0, 0, 10, 70));
        
        //hbox to hold both scores
        HBox hbThree = new HBox();
        hbThree.getChildren().addAll(playerScoreLbl, compScoreLbl);
        HBox.setMargin(playerScoreLbl, new Insets(0, 10, 10, 30));
        HBox.setMargin(compScoreLbl, new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10));
        
        //vbox to tie HBoxes together
        VBox statsVB = new VBox();
        statsVB.getChildren().addAll(hbOne, hbTwo, hbThree);
        
        //add to gridpane
        topPane.getChildren().add(statsVB);
        GridPane.setConstraints(statsVB, 2, 0);
        //end section two 
        
        //create new player
        Player player = new Player();
        //create new computer player
        Computer computer = new Computer();
        //button handler for textentry
        //user enters name, presses enter
        userEntryBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
            player.setName(userEntryTF.getText());
            gameplayTA.setText("Hello, " + player.getName() + ".\nLet's add money" +
                    " to your account.\nEnter $$ amount.");

        //here I want user to enter money amount, then press button
        //after button press, textArea asks user for bet amount..etc

        });
        return topPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(getTopPane(), 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("BLACKJACK");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }//end of main
}
```

Comment: Create one event handler for the button and place the logic to handle the action in the handler.  If that means, for your application, keeping track of state and running different logic based on the the state, then do that.  That is one option, there are others. If stuck, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

This is an implementation of @jewelsea suggestion in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76187159/how-to-create-multiple-onaction-listeners-for-a-single-button#comment134356872_76187159). It utilizes [setUserData](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData(java.lang.Object)) method of class `javafx.scene.Node` to keep track of the *state* mentioned in [@jewelsea] comment.

```java
package blackjack;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BlackJack extends Application {

    public GridPane getTopPane() {
        GridPane topPane = new GridPane();
        TextArea gameplayTA = new TextArea("Welcome to the table.\nWhat is your name?");
        gameplayTA.setEditable(false);
        gameplayTA.setPrefRowCount(3);
        gameplayTA.setPrefColumnCount(3);
        HBox userEntryHB = new HBox();
        TextField userEntryTF = new TextField("");
        Button userEntryBtn = new Button("ENTER");
        userEntryBtn.setUserData(0);
        userEntryBtn.disableProperty().bind(userEntryTF.textProperty().isEmpty());
        userEntryHB.getChildren().addAll(userEntryTF, userEntryBtn);
        HBox.setMargin(userEntryTF, new Insets(10, 5, 10, 0));
        HBox.setMargin(userEntryBtn, new Insets(10, 5, 10, 0));
        VBox gameplayVB = new VBox();
        gameplayVB.getChildren().addAll(gameplayTA, userEntryHB);
        VBox.setMargin(gameplayTA, new Insets(10, 5, 5, 10));
        VBox.setMargin(userEntryHB, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10));
        topPane.getChildren().add(gameplayVB);
        GridPane.setConstraints(gameplayVB, 0, 0);
        TextField playerBankTF = new TextField("");
        playerBankTF.setEditable(false);
        TextField compBankTF = new TextField("");
        compBankTF.setEditable(false);
        TextField betAmountTF = new TextField("");
        betAmountTF.setEditable(false);
        TextField playerScoreTF = new TextField("");
        playerScoreTF.setEditable(false);
        TextField compScoreTF = new TextField("");
        compScoreTF.setEditable(false);
        playerBankTF.setPrefWidth(80);
        compBankTF.setPrefWidth(80);
        betAmountTF.setPrefWidth(80);
        playerScoreTF.setPrefWidth(40);
        compScoreTF.setPrefWidth(40);
        Label playerBankLbl = new Label("Player Bank: ", playerBankTF);
        Label compBankLbl = new Label("Computer Bank: ", compBankTF);
        Label betAmountLbl = new Label("Bet Amount: ", betAmountTF);
        Label playerScoreLbl = new Label("Player Score: ", playerScoreTF);
        Label compScoreLbl = new Label("Computer Score: ", compScoreTF);
        playerBankLbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
        compBankLbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
        betAmountLbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
        playerScoreLbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
        compScoreLbl.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
        HBox hbOne = new HBox();
        hbOne.getChildren().addAll(playerBankLbl, compBankLbl);
        HBox.setMargin(playerBankLbl, new Insets(20, 10, 10, 10));
        HBox.setMargin(compBankLbl, new Insets(20, 10, 10, 10));
        HBox hbTwo = new HBox();
        hbTwo.getChildren().add(betAmountLbl);
        HBox.setMargin(betAmountLbl, new Insets(0, 0, 10, 70));
        HBox hbThree = new HBox();
        hbThree.getChildren().addAll(playerScoreLbl, compScoreLbl);
        HBox.setMargin(playerScoreLbl, new Insets(0, 10, 10, 30));
        HBox.setMargin(compScoreLbl, new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10));
        VBox statsVB = new VBox();
        statsVB.getChildren().addAll(hbOne, hbTwo, hbThree);
        topPane.getChildren().add(statsVB);
        GridPane.setConstraints(statsVB, 2, 0);
        
        //create new player
        Player player = new Player();

        userEntryBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
            Integer step = (Integer) userEntryBtn.getUserData();
            switch (step) {
                case 0:
                    player.setName(userEntryTF.getText());
                    gameplayTA.setText("Hello, " + player.getName() + ".\nLet's add money" +
                                       " to your account.\nEnter $$ amount.");
                    userEntryBtn.setUserData(1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    gameplayTA.setText("Place your bet.");
                    userEntryBtn.setUserData(2);
                    break;
                default:
                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING, "Unhandled: " + step, ButtonType.CLOSE);
                    alert.showAndWait();
            }
        });
        return topPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(getTopPane(), 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setTitle("BLACKJACK");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```